# Model namespace issue in rails

Tags: ruby, namespaces, ruby-1.9

I am having an issue with namespaces in Rails 3.1. I have a class, let's call it a.

```
#/app/models/a.rb
class a
  #some methods
  def self.method_from_a
    #does things
  end
end
```

But I also have another class that has the same name in a different namespace.

```
#/app/models/b/a.rb
class b::a
  def method
    return a.method_from_a
  end
end
```

When I call b::a.method though I get:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant b::a::a
```

I am sure it is a simple solution, I am just missing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prefix `a` with `::`:

```
class b::a
  def method
    return ::a.method_from_a
  end
end
```

This, (i.e. the scope operator) is also explained [here](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/language.html):

> Constants defined within a class or module may be accessed unadorned
>   anywhere within the class or module. Outside the class or module, they
>   may be accessed using the scope operator, `::'' prefixed by an
>   expression that returns the appropriate class or module object.
>   Constants defined outside any class or module may be accessed
>   unadorned or by using the scope operator`::'' with no prefix.

By the way, in Ruby class names should start with an upper case letter.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I knew I was just missing something simple.