# Namespaced Models not being called properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activemodel

In my app i have the following models:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
 #attr: :title
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class User::Category < ActiveRecord::Base
 #attr: :description
end
```

Everything looks so much tidier now that i have this folder structure, but here is the funny thing:
When i run something like:

```
User::Category.last.description
```

Rails SOMETIMES thinks i am referring to *Category* rather then *User::Category*, which breaks the app since description is not an attribute. Any idea? This is the second time i see this problem and no idea how to fix it? Sometimes it works with the proper Model, sometime it gets the model model without namespace!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Model namespace issue in rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8969240/model-namespace-issue-in-rails)

Answer (score 0):

guessing `User::Category.last` is returning an object of class `Category`, as you had noticed.

if you're wanting to have `last` return a different object, would be a question of modifying `last`, could monkey patch in User::Category:

```
class User::Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  def last
    self
  end
end
```

I would go with STI.

could add `type` attribute to `Category` of type `string`

then

```
class UserCategory < Category
  attr_reader :description
end
```

or if you already have a description attr backed by AR on the category object, could go with monkey patch approach

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance.html

Comment: my goal was to keep the folder structure clean. I was trying to avoid any user_category.rb, user_post.rb etcetcetc in my /model  folder

Comment: would be a question of editing `last`, or could monkey patch `last`

Comment: @pastullo also, revised answer with what if I had to guess would be a way to go about with your approach